# Unable to update field to required using SOAP/Wsproxy

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, dataextensions

We are using SOAP/WSProxy to update a field to required using the following Update call:

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Header>
      <wsse:Security soap:mustunderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         [...]
      </wsse:Security>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <UpdateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xmlns:ns2="urn:fault.partner.exacttarget.com">
         <Objects xsi:type="DataExtension" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <CustomerKey>DE_CUSTOMERKEY</CustomerKey>
            <Client>
         <ID>7325541</ID>
      </Client>
            <Fields>
               <Field>
                  <ObjectID>cd392a43-ff4f-4e91-a3d6-e69bc64d02f7</ObjectID>                  
                  <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>               
               </Field>
            </Fields>
         </Objects>
      </UpdateRequest>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The response is:

```
<StatusCode>Error</StatusCode>
<StatusMessage>The field "SOME_FIELD" cannot be changed to be required on update because it was created to allow nulls</StatusMessage>
```

The same response comes from WSProxy.

The data extension is not sendable, its empty and the field is not related to any relationship nor attribute group.

Comment: Maybe is has something to do with 'IsNillable' field. But I cannot retrieve this field

Comment: I'm not sure but the issue should be related to SOAP API. SOAP API is the system that you can use to interact with Email Studio (Exact Target legacy) and with the standard UI of Email Studio you can't change a "nullable" field to a "non nullable field". You can do this only using Contact Builder UI.

Comment: Yes, its as @Frogmouth points, confimed by SFMC support. You can only change a not nullable to nullable, not the other way round.

Comment: I created a small blog post a while ago on handling a similar issue (DE had to be recreated to edit Pkeys) if you want to check it out. This was fastest way I have found to do it adhoc - https://gortonington.com/changing-primary-keys-on-data-extensions/

Comment: The way it woks: -You CANNOT change nullable to required in Email Studio, nor SOAP. - You CAN change nullable to required in ContactBuilder* EXCEPT if the field has been linked in an Attribute Set as part of a Data Delationship.

Comment: @Gortonington, thanks for the info. Our problem is that we need to change a DE in 10 BUs and this DE is being used in multiple automations, I think we will remove the data relationship, delete the field, recreate it as PK, recreate the data relationship and relaunch the automations involved, hope it works.